# Is it necessary for rownum = 1 with Query.createQuery().getSingleResult()?

Tags: oracle

I'm a newie and I'm not really sure if MIN(My_Date) returns just one row if 2 or more dates are identical.

Reference is a FOREIGN KEY.

so to limit query:

```
SELECT MIN(Shipping_Date) 
FROM Com_Order 
WHERE Reference = 'X' and rownum = 1
GROUP BY Reference;
```

This second query seems to have same results just one value..

```
SELECT MIN(Shipping_Date) 
FROM Com_Order 
WHERE Reference = 'X';
```

I'm using JPA, so is it redundant to use rownum = 1 and GROUP BY Reference if I use `Query.creatQuery().getSingleResult()`? Are the 2 queries the same?

Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the two queries is that the 2nd will always return 1 row. Even if the table is empty or just has 0 rows with `reference=X`, the result will be 1 row with `null` in the `min(date)` column.

The first query will return no row in this case. The `and rownum=1` is useless and does not affect anything for the specific query.

Test at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/342394/5).